# как получить доступ к видеопотоку с IP камеры в UWP приложении?

Tags: c#, uwp

Я нашел несколько IP камер, но проблема в том, что по этим адресам я могу получить только mjpg, а мне нужен поток видео с минимальной задержкой, есть ли способ это сделать?

1. http://213.193.89.202/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=192619
2. http://213.34.225.97:8080/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=25748
3. http://81.149.56.38:8084/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=796
4. http://217.128.111.137:8081/view/view.shtml?id=0&imagepath=%2Fmjpg%2F1%2Fvideo.mjpg&size=1

Comment: если камера не предоставляет "видео потока с минимальной задержкой", то Вы его нигде не возьмете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот эти подтормаживания кадров видео - это или ограничение в настройках камеры (вряд ли) или же ограничение железа камеры (плохие камеры)

Если ты заглянешь в характеристики камеры то увидишь что-то вроде

480p - 25 fps
720p - 15 fps
1080p - 10 fps

Но даже то что пишут обычно они в х-ках камера округляют в большую сторону. Даже в средней и высокой ценовой категории камер такое практикуется, к сожалению. Поэтому покупая камеру где пишут 720p - 25 кадров - будь готов к тому что она будет показывать в лучшем случае 22 кадра в секунду.

---

Если же под задержкой имеется ввиду задержка перед передачей события - то это уже второй блок ограничений. Это как зависит от железа камер(камеры с централизированным контрольным блоком обычно имеют меньшие задержки, в отличии от "Standalone" камер), так и зависит от подключения к интернету конкретной камеры, нагруженности сети, подключения к интернету принимающей стороны и т.д.

Соответственно ни с тем ни с другим ты ничего сделать не можешь, если камеры не твои. Если камеры твои - купи камеры по-дороже и с централизированным контрольным блоком.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать FFmpegInterop https://github.com/microsoft/FFmpegInterop для того, чтобы установить rtsp поток с камеры в качестве источника для элемента MediaElement в XAML:

```
        ffmpeg = await FFmpegInterop.FFmpegInteropMSS.CreateFromUriAsync("rtsp://88.84.52.66/axis-media/media.amp");
        MediaStreamSource streamSource = ffmpeg.GetMediaStreamSource();
        mediaElement.SetMediaStreamSource(streamSource);
        mediaElement.Play();
```